# Treat all class properties as dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to know if it is possible to make all class properties as separate dictionaries.

For example:

```
class myclass:
     def __init__(self, bar):
         self.foo = bar
```

Internally, what I would this class to do is that when calling `self.foo = bar` (setting `foo`), I want it do do `self.foo.value = bar` and when getting `foo`, I want it to internally get `self.foo.value`.

I want to do this so I can store other information for each class property (like ‘info’ or 'comment').

Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Did you take a look at [`__getattr__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__)/[`__setattr__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setattr__) magic methods?

Comment: Also, [properties](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property), depending on how much flexibility you need.